# Draw line relative to Image position and scale

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a game in Unity and I have a Canvas set to Screen Space - Overlay and it has that background green as you can see from the image. I also have a RawImage with the background blue as a child of the Canvas and the player will have to draw an object like a car or a house inside the RawImage.Right now, the line Instantiates in a random position on the screen even if I give it the coordinated (0, 0).
What I need help with is to find a way to convert the coordinates so I only work with the inside coordinates of the RawImage. For example, the (0, 0) coordinate I will pass to the line, has to be converted to the bottom-left corner of the RawImage. and the maximum width or height should also depend on the RawImage width and height.
[image]

Here is the CreateLine function I have for now:

```
public void CreateLine(int x, int y)
{
    currentLine = Instantiate(linePrefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
    currentLine.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("GameMenu(Clone)").transform; //Make the line a child of the Canvas named GameMenu
    lineRenderer = currentLine.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, new Vector3(x, y, 99));
    lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, new Vector3(x, y, 99));
}
```

Any amount of help will be greatly appreciated. Have a great day!

Comment: Your lines positions are in world space, not in reference to your RawImage. You can probably get your world space references from the [RawImage.rectTransform.rect](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/RectTransform-rect.html) and use [TransformPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformPoint.html) to get the world space bounds of your image. Then you can use your coordinates to lerp inside those bounds to draw within the space of the image.